# How to handle hitting same request after every 20sec in loadrunner

Tags: vugen, loadrunner

I am scripting for an application in which there is a search to be done and when search is hit after entering required parameters the request is sent to the server after 20 sec the request is passes with 200 response code and automatically send same request again every 20sec until actual response is received. Does anyone came across this kind of application. Please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: It's not generated by human, it's auto generated

Comment: Then it is the same for any other report with a polling mechanism.  You implement a loop with an exit condition when the report is satisfied.  Inside of the loop you have a request with the delay interval for the polling implemented as a sleep() in milliseconds